# Edit Shipping Address on existing order

Tags: commerce

Is there any way to edit the shipping address on an existing order? I only see the billing address in the edit screen.

Comment: Needs more info; what's your Drupal version, what modules / how have you configured them power your shipping info?

Comment: @RyanSzrama Looks like I have just the same issue. On a page like /admin/commerce/orders/[id]/edit - there is a billing address which I can edit, but no shipping address block at all. How can we add it there? Drupal 8.5.6, Commerce 2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that works in all cases, but in mine - I managed to enable shipping form this way:

1. go to Home >> Administration >> Commerce >> Configuration >>
   Order types >> Edit [your order type]
   (/admin/commerce/config/order-types/[order_type]/edit/form-display)
2. select "Manage form display" there
3. find "Shipments" line there
4. switch it to `Inline entity form - Complex`

And instead of autocomplete for shipments I got form with edit button that allows me to change shipping address for order.

Order display settings screen:
[image: Display settings screen]

Edit order page shipping block after update:

[image: shipments list on edit order page]